# I can not restore vm deleted accidentally in google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

Do you know if is possible restore a vm, that was deleted accidentally in Compute Engine.
I tried to search a option but i dont find it

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: To avoid such situations you should create snapshots [manually](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) or even better [on schedule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots). Also you can [protect](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion) your VM from accidental deletetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had snapshots of it it is pretty easy to do this and follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) on how to do it.

If not, there is most likely no chance of ever recovering it.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to restore VM without snapshot.